# Sharing methods between two implementations of a virtual base class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, class

I have a virtual base class and two classes that implement the various methods. The two classes have the same functionality for one of the methods. Is there away I can share the implementation between the two classes to eliminate redundant code? I tried making the first class a parent of the second class in addition to the virtual base class but got a bunch of errors.

**EDIT** - Thanks everyone for the replies. One thing I should have mentioned is that I cannot modify the virtual base class so just adding the code to the base class will not work.

Comment: what do u mean by virtual base i.e. abstract class or virtually inherited from other class ?

Comment: Everything is declared with virtual methodname() = 0;

Comment: @blcArmadillo: It is an *abstract* base class and not virtual base class. Virtual base class has totally different meaning in C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say, `A` is the base class, and `B` and `C` are classes that inherit from the base class.  The method whose logic is shared between `B` and `C` is called `SomeMethod`.  One of the following should do the trick, regardless of your use case:

- Take the logic for `B::SomeMethod` and `C::SomeMethod` and copy-and-paste it into `A::SomeMethod`
- Create a class `D` that provides the shared version of `SomeMethod` and have `B` and `C` derive from `D`, which will derive from `A`
- Create a class `SomeMethodImpl` that just provides the implementation you want, and then the implementation of `B::SomeMethod` and `C::SomeMethod` will just delegate the method call to a private instance of `SomeMethodImpl::SomeMethod`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your base class as pure virtual, create another class that inherits from this one and implements that one function, and then have your two other classes inherit from this one:

```
class Base { public: virtual void TheFunction(); /* blah blah other virtual functions */ };
class OneFunctionImplemented : public Base { public: virtual void TheFunction() { DoSomething(); } };
class ChildClass1 : public OneFunctionImplemented { };
class ChildClass2 : public OneFunctionImplemented { };
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the shared functionality in the base class. Both of the other classes will be able to access it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe by virtual base class you mean a base class having a pure virtual function (an *abstract* class) and not deriving virtually from a base class. If this is the case, you can put the common implementation in this base class so that it is available for all the derived classes.